# Mobile Device Managed Single App Devices

Tags: android, mdm, device-policy-manager, samsung-knox, cosu

I like to have single android app in our managed devices, we want only that app to be used on the device with necessary restriction, such that,

1. Single use - Device will have only one app, user can't use other apps, like browsing, youtube or anything,
2. the initial setting like notification sound, GPS always on, notification and ring sound maximum level can't be modified.
3. user can not power off the device.
4. this setting can only be changed by our servers.

i think i have 2 option,

1) Using samsung knox sdk on samsung devices,
 Here's MDM proving feature of [Samsung Knox Standard](https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/knox-standard-android)!

2) General Android way, Set up Single-Purpose Devices, COSU solution
[Android Developer's site](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#cosu-solutions).

Wanted to know your's view on this, may be if you guys have done any of the two or any other ways, i could use some of the guidelines or a path.

***Thanks for reading, and please comment if i was unable to articulate the subject or it needs editing.***

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's new [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=44846300), it seems to suit your needs.

It is a new cloud API that allows to manage Android devices from a server, without having to build an on-device agent (a device policy controller).

Answer (score 1):

I have broad experience of using Samsung Kiosk Mode from Knox Standard SDK which is free and Pro-Kiosk mode from Knox Customization SDK (which has more functions but is not free).

So I can tell you for sure that all 4 points that you have mentioned can be achieved by using Knox Standard SDK.

1. Singe Purpose: https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/kioskmode/KioskMode.html
2. LocationPolicy (you can turn on GPS and restrict changing): https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/android/app/enterprise/LocationPolicy.html
3. Yes. It is possible but I forgot the exact implementation.
4. Yes, as well.

Only downside of using this SDK is:

You are tied to Samsung (which I personally okay with, since Samsung has such market penetration and you could get service almost anywhere in the world and in enterprise world it is critical)

About Android native functionality: never tried it

Update March 7, 2019: Now I am playing around Device Owner, we use it for Kiosk mode, works well and works on android Device with Nougat and earlier.

Comment: is there a way to disable knox prokiosk mode with ADB commands f.e.? Am strugling to figure out scripted way with S9 / Android Pie

Comment: @ahaaman no. Only invoking API to disable Kiosk mode or factory reset if it it not blocked